# How to speed up copy_expert in postgresql?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sql-update, django-queryset

The following function imports around 60k records in 111 seconds. I've heard others say that copy_from and copy_expert are doing 1 million records in less than a minute. Is there something about using copy_expert that is slowing down process vs using copy_from? Anything I can do to optimize this?

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.copy_expert('''
COPY employee_employee (name, slug, title, base, overtime, other, gross, benefits, ual, total, year, status, jurisdiction_id, notes)
FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true, FORCE_NOT_NULL (status));
''', open(csv_fname),
)
```

As for relevant variables the database connection is from Django (`from django.db import connection`). The database is on my local Macbook Pro and is PostgreSQL 10.

Answer (score 1):

Specify buffering=2**10 in your file open.

I thought this was a problem with psycopg2 on OSX.  I had the same problem, and it ran super fast on ubuntu. It was slow on OSX regardless of whether the database was on OSX and Ubuntu.  My copy_expert was taking 13 minutes on OSX. When I changed buffering=2**10 it went from 13 minutes to 7 seconds.

Comment: Can you please explain more please. Is it in built in function `open(file, mode='r', buffering=- 1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`  ? buffering?

I have this issue with pipelinewise app. It uses copy_expert command that is slow.

Comment: @SlavaLenskyy when you open the file don't set "buffering=-1", rather, set buffering much larger.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the great **django-postgres-copy**, which I used to import easily som CSV with ~1 million rows in few seconds directly to PostgreSQL.

It's made by the California Civic Data Coalition, to import and export delimited data with Django support for PostgreSQL's COPY command.

> *"This package tries to make using COPY as easy as any other database routine supported by Django. It is implemented by a custom model manager."*

Here’s how it imports a CSV to a database table.

```
from myapp.models import MyModel

MyModel.objects.from_csv("./data.csv", dict(name='NAME', number='NUMBER'))
```

And here’s how it exports a database table to a CSV.

```
from myapp.models import MyModel

MyModel.objects.to_csv("./data.csv")
```

Read the **django-postgres-copy** [documentation](https://github.com/california-civic-data-coalition/django-postgres-copy) to have more information.